# What is the expected value of min of three random variables?

Tags: probability

> Suppose that $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3$ denote a random sample from an exponential
>   distribution with density function
>
> $$ f(y)=\begin{cases}
>      \frac{1}{\theta}e^{\frac{-y}{\theta}}, & \text{if $x>0$}.\\
>     0, & \text{otherwise}.   \end{cases}$$
>
> Consider the following five estimator of $\theta$:
>
> $\hat{\theta}_1=Y_1$    $\hat{\theta}_2=\frac{Y_1+ Y_2}{3}$
>   $\hat{\theta}_3=\frac{Y_1+ 2Y_2}{3}$  $\hat{\theta}_4=
>  \min(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)$ .

So I was able to calculate $E[Y]=\theta$, so the first three options work(I simple used the linearity of expectation to workout that expected value of the estimator is $\theta$). But I don't know how to calculate the expected value of 
minimum of some random variables. Furthermore, I'm wondering if you pick samples from a given distribution then are the samples necessarily iid?

Comment: This is a question from "Mathematical statistics with applications 7th edition" by Wackerly Mendenhall, Scheaffer p.394 q8.8 in case you need reference

Comment: The second option has a bias. To compute the minimum value, you can use the so called "Law of the unconscious statistician" and the fact that the minimum of two independent exponential r.v. is again an exponential r.v. to simplify the computation. And usually, when no precision are added, you are supposed to make the simplest hypothesis, e.g. in this case independent and identically distributed.

Comment: sorry, how do we find the minimum of two independent exponential? also, how do we know that they are independent? I don't understand

Comment: The theorem I mentionned (Law of ...) will allow you to find the expectancy of the minimum of exponential r.v.. And usually, when a statement (in a exercise for example) does not tell you that the r.v. are dependent, then they are independent. Since nothing is said about de the dependence of the sample and the statement is using the word "random", you can assume they are independent.

Comment: I've never heard it called that, but the proof is pretty easy. For simplicity, let $\beta = 1/\theta$. Let cdf$_\beta$ be the cdf of an exponential distribution with inverse parameter $\beta$.

\begin{align*}
P(\min(Y_1,Y_2) \geq y) &= P(\{Y_1 \geq y\}\cap\{Y_2 \geq y\})= P(Y_1 \geq y)p(Y_2 \geq y)\\
&= (1 - \text{cdf}_\beta(y))^2 = (e^{-\beta y})^2 \\
&= e^{-2\beta y} = (1 - \text{cdf}_{2\beta}(y))
\end{align*}

So $\min(Y_1,Y_2)$ is exponentially distributed with inverse parameter $2\beta$ or parameter $\theta/2$. You can use a similar method to prove the more general theorem.